# TexLive linux installation - where do I choose to put symlinks?

Tags: texlive, installing

I am installing TexLive 2019 on Ubuntu through the install-tl  of a downloaded iso. 
There is an option to automatically create symlinks that I would like to use. However, the installer asks for three different paths.

What do you recommend I enter ?

Comment: Just enter the default options, when the installation is finished it will show them again for you to add them to `.bashrc`

Comment: the recommended choice is not to add symlinks